# HP 240 G2 ubuntu14.04 drivers

Tags: 14.04, drivers, hp

I have HP 240 G2 laptop with Intel i5 core and I have installed Ubuntu 14.04. My machine is dual boot with windows 10 in it. In windows 10 I can access everything like audio, screen brightness control, wifi and touchpad but when I boot ubuntu I can not access these four facilities i.e. audio, screen brightness, wifi and touchpad do not work at all. Wifi option is not at all seen in the network bar at the top only Ethernet option is show. Ethernet works and USB tithering works as well. Surprisingly bluetooth options is available to access but did not try to connect it to any device. I believe my laptop lacks drivers required. Please help with this.

Comment: Why not install Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Hi @Pilot6, does that work completely with this laptop hardware? I could try that if it works.

Comment: I have no idea what hardware is in this laptop, and noone knows that for sure. But it is more likely that a new release supports some hardware. If something does not work ask separate questions for each problem.

Comment: Okay I'll try that and update results here for others.

Answer (score 0):

goto
 settings-> software and updates-> 
click on other softwares -> select canonical partners-> 
then goto additional drivers, 
now it will update and show you broadcom device list. select on the first driver you see and apply it and check.